# How to convert/cast varchar to float?

Tags: sql-server

I just need to bulk update data. For this, I've created a table type and stored procedure.

I've created type with this:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[ItemsUpdate] AS TABLE
(
  [ItemPartNumber] [varchar](100) NULL,
  [VendorName]     [varchar](100) NULL,
  [Price]          [varchar](100) NULL
)
GO
```

And my stored procedure be like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateItemsByVendorPrice]
   @tblItemUpdate ItemsUpdate READONLY
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  MERGE INTO Items orgTable
  USING @tblItemUpdate typeTable ON orgTable.ItemPartNumber = typeTable.ItemPartNumber

  WHEN MATCHED THEN
     UPDATE SET orgTable.Price = CONVERT(FLOAT, typeTable.Price);
END
```

Even though, I used `convert(float,typeTable.Price)`, I got this error.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Error converting data type varchar to float

Comment: Why not create the column as the correct data type in the first place?

Comment: Obviously you are using C# so why aren't you using SqlBulkCopy? What you are doing is *not* the same as BULK INSERT - no simple logging mode, no batching, full locking on the tables. Moreover, you should *not* make conversions during insertions, the client should send the correct data type.

Comment: What @RonBeyer said, with the correct type being `decimal` not `float` since this is money (presumably).

Comment: A far more scalable option is to use SqlBulkCopy or any other bulk insert mechanism (bcp or BULK INSERT command) to load the data to a staging table and then execute either an UPDATE (if the data is only updates) or MERGE (if there are both inserts and updates)

Comment: @panagiotis: Can you please show me some working code of sqlbulkupdate? I cannot be able to find any!

Comment: @WP_Geek just google "SqlBulkCopy". The results are full of examples. In fact, the very first result is the documentation of the class itself which includes a full example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UPDATE SET orgTable.Price = convert(float,typeTable.Price);` says you want to convert the contents of `typeTable.Price` to a float. Likely you have bad data, something that can't be cast to a float, such as "foo" or improperly-localized data like `234,457`.

If you are using SQL 2012 or above, you can use `TRY_CONVERT` and setup a catch, like:

```
declare @myfloat float;
SELECT @myfloat = TRY_CONVERT(float, typeTable.Price)
IF @myfloat IS NULL then BEGIN
   PRINT 'Cast failed from '
   PRINT typeTable.Price
END
ELSE BEGIN
   PRINT 'cast OK'
   --continue update as normal
END
```

Note that TRY_CONVERT returns null or the converted value, so if you are working with data that could actually be null, you should filter that case explicitly before the TRY_CONVERT.

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty clear, you have information in that column that does not fit the datatype of the column it is being inserted into.

You need to clean your data before trying to insert it. Apparently you have things in the price column in the data that are not actual prices. Usually these involve values for things like 'Call for Price' or 'N/A' in the part number files I have processed.

How you handle this depends on your business rules. If it is OK to dump values that do not have real prices you just need to filter for that. If is is not ok to have prices that are not money, then you need to fail the import and send the database to the person providing it for a fix. You might also need to skip those records but send them back to the provider so they can fix for future imports. All these are business decisions that only your organization can answer. Once you know what the business decision is, we can help show you how to implement it.

As a side note, do not use merge for this, you are only doing updates, so just use an update statement. Plus merge has flaws, I don't usually recommend it for use in production data. - http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/

One thing that especially bothers me is that you will be updating all matching parts not just teh ones that changed price. That is significantly more work than the server needs to do. An update without a where clause is usually a poor choice. Never plan to update receords that don't need to be updated. This is especially true of you have a large file. Why update a million records when you only have 3 that changed? But even with small files, it is good to get into the habit of doing this correctly, so that when you do update a large dataset, the technique is natural to you.